# Mount a iscsi target volume natively

Tags: linux, filesystems, iscsi

I have a LVM logic volumn exported though iscsi and formatted by the client to ext4.

Now that machine serving the iscsi target went down and I'm wondering if I can just take the hard disk out to another machine and mount it natively without using iscsi?

Answer (score 0):

If you truly exported the entire hard drive via `/dev/sda` or similar, then yes, you can mount it natively.

Comment: It is a bit more complicate than this. It is a lvm logical volumn. But I thought for iscsi, it will simply treat it as a hard disk, right ? I am trying to mount it but unfornately it says no fs type is recognised.

Comment: What, exactly, did you export? Edit your original question to include your iSCSI target configuration.

Comment: I used the openfiler to export the iSCSI target. so i'm not sure what configuration they use.. Will it matter?

Comment: Yes, it matters. And the fact that this is openfiler should have been shared to begin with. I don't know how openfiler implements iSCSI exports at the disk level.